# Post request not reaching server from iOS device

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

Trying to make simple post request to a remote PHP file. I'm not receiving the parameters on the server. Which I receive using Postman Btw. So the service seems ok. Something seems to be missing the iOS code here.

```
- (void) sendPostRequest {
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseURLPost];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"JSON", @"responseType",
                         [UserManager sharedInstance].user.username, @"username",
                            self.textView.text, @"text",
                         nil];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSDebugDescription"]);
    } else {
       NSArray *jsonResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponseArray);
    }
}] resume];
}
```

My PHP code to receive post REquest.

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");

$postText= $_POST['text'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$itemType = $_POST['itemType'];
$responseType = $_POST['responseType'];
$pictureLink = $_POST['pictureLink'];
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
$tags = $_POST['tags'];

if($timestamp==null){
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
}
$arr = array('username' => $username);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The `jsonResponseArray` from this is  `username = "<null>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally re-wrote whole iOS class in Swift and stuff started rolling again. the PHP services have been around a while and have worked fine for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r'); 
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
```

instead of `$_POST`

Like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:application/json");

$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$arr = json_decode($jsonInput, true);

$postText= $arr['text'];
$username = $arr['username'];
$itemType = $arr['itemType'];
$responseType = $arr['responseType'];
$pictureLink = $arr['pictureLink'];
$timestamp = $arr['timestamp'];
$tags = $arr['tags'];

if($timestamp==null){
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
}
$arr = array('username' => $username);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help with the php code. I still want to keep the question open for a few days, My php code is really old and has worked for me in the past. I'm hoping someone will help me some with my obj-c and I won't have to change my php code so much.

Comment: @BabakT can you explain why this works, over using $_POST? I have the same issue, sending JSON to the server using a POST request from my objC app, but I can only access the JSON using the php://input fopen call. I'm curious why.

Answer (score 0):

Not true to your answer, but this code has worked for me :

```
//Dict -> your dictionary, url -> the url for the action

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict 
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&error];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];

NSString *postLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[data length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

//....
//rest of the code
```

Comment: Seems like only postLenth is different.

Comment: this exact code has been working for me for a long time with a PHP server. thot it might be of help.